# MySql Querys - Slow server

Tags: php, mysqli, centos, mariadb, mysql-slow-query-log

I have a CentOS 7 server.

Since a few days the server behavior has been critically slow due a lot of mysql querys in the web app we have there.

I´ve tried to setup mariaDB server.cnf to log the slow-querys and the general-querys whitout having any response or log, I don´t know why it isn´t log any query.

Please help...

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 0):

The setup for the logs is rather convoluted.

You also need

```
log_output = FILE
```

Comment: @AndresZambrano - What is the value of `slow_query_log_file`?

Comment: More discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog